# Some images not displaying on jQuery Mobile app built with Phonegap

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile, cross-platform, phonegap-build

I created a cross platform app using jQuery Mobile. When I test it on various browsers it works fine and displays all images with no problems. When I build it with Phonegap Build, transfer to my Android phone and test I have problems with some images displaying.

I have several similar pages where I display a picture on each page. The problem is that pictures display on some pages but not on others. I have ruled out file type as an issue (I am using .jpg, .jpeg and .png and I have at least 1 of each of these working fine) and I have ruled out the code as the issue as I have used working images on pages that werent displaying the image before to prove that it was the image itself at fault (the image displayed fine when I used one that was working from another page). I have also ruled out picture size, dpi and dimensions.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any correlation on the file name itself for the images that are not working?

Comment: No, I cant see anything common about them that could be the issue

Comment: Could you add some code so we can see how the images are included? without a visible thing, it's going to be more guessing than anything. I would say check the file name cases, as android is case sensitive (mypic.JPG <> mypic.jpg). If you test on Windows (case insensitive), the pages will work on the browsers, but they will fail on android.

Comment: Alvaro, thank you very much, you were right, it was the file type case that was the problem. I assumed .jpg and .png was ok but some of the images were named ....PNG and ...JPG instead of lower case. I changed the filenames and they worked. Thank you, much appreciated!